# ios7 interface orientation - restrict orientation to particular viewcontroller

Tags: ios, orientation

I have two UIViewControllers in my UINavigationController stack, in which i need to support portrait and landscape orientations for the first viewController alone and for the second viewController, i need portrait support alone and not landscape.

In ViewController1, I have implemented the following methods,

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}

-(void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
[self changeFrames:toInterfaceOrientation]; //changing frames for orientation accordingly
}
```

and in ViewController2:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
return NO;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Also in project target, i have set to support all the 4 orientations.

Looking for any kind of help to solve the above issue.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What is the behaviour that you have from this implementation that is not what you want?